# What do speciation curves really represent?

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium

So I'm just reading about speciation diagrams in my textbook...and I'm very confused.[image]

I get how you work out that the crossover point in when [A-] = [HA] mathematically...but I don't understand it in relation to what an equilibrium constant represents. My understanding was that equilibrium constants represent a ratio that is ALWAYS true for that reaction. So, for instance, at the beginning of this diagram where the pH is low (lots of protons)...I get that this drives the equilibrium to the left (hence the high mole ratio of the protonated form)...however, shouldn't the ratio of acid/base form still equal the acid dissociation constant (Ka)? Sorry if this makes little sense but I'm really struggling to reconcile this with what I've learnt about equilibrium constants in general.

Comment: > shouldn't the ratio of acid/base form still equal the acid dissociation constant (Ka)?" 

No, 

$$K_\text{a} = \frac{\ce{[H+]}\ce{[CH3COO]}}{\ce{[CH3COOH]}}$$ 

You are forgetting that the $\ce{H+}$  concentration ($\ce{[H+]}$) is also present in the equilibrium expression.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I do understand that. I meant to ask, is that ratio still satisfied at every point in that graph? Because I thought when you 'disturbed' an equilibrium, the reaction shifts - according to Le Chatelier - to maintain this ratio (the Ka value).

Comment: Yes that ratio is satisfied (assuming activities can be approximated by concentrations, but never mind that for now). Le Chateliers principle still holds.

Comment: ok...i think I'm starting to grasp it thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Forget about equilibrium constants when you try to read speciation curves. They are derived from equilibrium calculations though. If you are interest you should derive the mathematical relations yourself by defining what is the concentration ratio (Search speciation diagram acetic acid). It will satisfy you if you can draw then in Excel yourself.

Reading it is very simple. The y-axis represents the fraction of two molecular species obtained from acetic acid and the x- axis is the pH.

Say at pH 1, almost 100% of the solute exists as CH$_3$COOH, and almost 0% is CH$_3$COO$^-$
Say at pH 6, more than 95% of solute exists as  CH$_3$COO$^-$ and less than 5% exists as CH$_3$COOH.

Similarly try to read the what is happening at the pKa of acetic acid.

Comment: I'll add that the pH where the two curves intersect is the pKa of acetic acid.

Comment: Yes I understand how to read the graph...but I don't want to ignore the equilibrium constant because that's what's causing my confusion. Is it not correct to say that the equilibrium constant ratio should always be satisfied...and is it satisfied here?

Comment: You really have to look at the derivation. Believe it or not it not take more 3-4 steps. One should not talk about curves qualitatively. Lets us start from defining what your y-axis is from acetic acid and for acetate ion. Write an algebraic expression for both.

Comment: ok. It's the mole ratio...so for acetic acid its n(acetic acid)/n(total) where n(total) = n(acetic acid)+n(acetate ion)?

Comment: @MatH - Yes that's it. I just noticed that the Y-axis is labeled "molar ratio" which is really incorrect. What is graphed is rather the "mole fraction."  So the blue curve isn't $\frac{\ce{[HA]}}{\ce{[A-]}}$ but rather $\frac{\ce{[HA]}}{\ce{[HA] + [A-]}}$

Comment: Right, so you can write that in terms in concentrations  as molar conc (acetic acid)/ molar  conc. (total). Also write the equilibrium expression Ka for acetic acid.

Comment: Ka = [CH3Coo-][H3O+]/{CH3COOH]

Comment: Correct, now you have two equations, now we want to eliminate [HA] and [A-] from [HA]/([HA]+[A−] ) for acetic acid so that we can find an expression which contains [H+] and Ka only in this ratio. What if we rearrange the Ka expression and write [HA]=[A-][H+]/Ka. Substitute this value and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite the equilibrium constant expression, you get:

$$\frac{K}{\ce{[H+]}} = \frac{\ce{[CH3COO-]}}{\ce{[CH3COOH]}}$$

So the ratio of the two species is equal to the ratio of equilibrium constant to proton concentration. Accordingly, the ratio changes with pH, and is equal to one when the pH is equal to the pKa.

At each pH value in your graph, the acid/base reaction is at equilibrium (so the the equilibrium constant expression with the concentrations plugged into it will have the same value (= K).

You might think the graph should be a straight line. It is a curve because the x-axis is showing the pH and not the proton concentration, and because the y-axis is showing the fraction of the species and not the ratio. If you plot log(ratio) against pH, you get a straight line.

Comment: Dear Karsten, I am afraid this explanation is partially incorrect. The y-axis is wrong in student's textbook.The graph of the so called alpha functions of acetic acid is not a plot of ratio of conjugate base over acid concentration.

Comment: As $$\alpha=\frac{1}{1+\frac{\ce{[A-]}}{\ce[HA]}}$$

Comment: @M.Farooq "...because the y-axis is showing the fraction of the species and not the ratio", i.e. Poutnik's alpha.